# Nodejs and amqplib: Can't prefetch more than one message

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq

So, i'm trying to learn how to create a rabbitmq consumer in node.js. I have been following the tutorials in rabbitmq website.

I'm working with queues and I wanted to fetch more than 1 message at a time. I tried passing 5 to `ch.prefetch`, but it still only fetches one message per consume call.

The code i'm using is:

```
var amqp = require('amqplib');

amqp.connect('amqp://localhost').then(function(conn) {
  process.once('SIGINT', function() { conn.close(); });
  return conn.createChannel().then(function(ch) {
    var ok = ch.assertQueue('task_queue', {durable: true});
    ok = ok.then(function() { ch.prefetch(5); });
    ok = ok.then(function() {
      ch.consume('task_queue', doWork, {noAck: false});
      console.log(" [*] Waiting for messages. To exit press CTRL+C");
    });
    return ok;

    function doWork(msg) {
      var body = msg.content.toString();
      console.log(" [x] Received '%s'", body);
      var secs = body.split('.').length - 1;
      //console.log(" [x] Task takes %d seconds", secs);
      setTimeout(function() {
        console.log(" [x] Done");
        ch.ack(msg);
      }, secs * 1000);
    }
  });
}).then(null, console.warn);
```

From this example [here](https://github.com/squaremo/amqp.node/blob/master/examples/tutorials/worker.js).

Am I missing something? Why isn't it retrieving more than 1 message at a time?

Thanks

Comment: How do you know it's not pre-fetching the messages? It's important to distinguish pre-fetching from processing the message. Pre-fetching means that Rabbit will send `n` messages to each consumer's client-side prefetch buffer, but they will still be processed one at a time. Pre-fetching is useful if your consumer is fast so it's not waiting for messages to be delivered as it's processing.

Comment: That explains a lot. I thought that when prefetching more than one I would receive an array as parameter in `doWork`. Thanks for clearing that out.